# Why is my Wacom Cintiq Companion eraser not erasing in sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting

When I switch to sculpt mode and use my eraser with my wacom cintiqu companion, blender version 2.77a will display a red dashed circle inside the drawing brush icon and will not allow erasing. When the 'subtract' brush is activated, it will erase like normal, but not with the eraser. I have not been able to find a solution on the internet yet. If someone could help me, I would much appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to BSE Nikolai. As far as I know there is no erase in sculpt mode - Add pulls the vertex along the normal outward, and Subtract pushes them in. You can either do this by the menu buttons or holding down  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  to reverse the operation. The eraser still works but has no function on the meshes. If you had for example grease pencil strokes, you could erase those even though you are in Sculpt mode. The same is also true of Edit mode.